# This if statement doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Play with it here: http://jsbin.com/ocicu4/4/edit

Simple Accordion, I only want one section open at a time.

I figured the if statement would work, but it doesn't.

```
        // Clicks on h3 show .sectionContent
        $('h3.sectionHeading').click(function() {
            if ($('h3.sectionHeading').next().is('.open')) {
                // Do nothing
            } else {
                // Find the exsisting div.open remove class and close it
                $('div.open').removeClass('open').animate(
                    {'height':'toggle'}, 'fast', 'linear'
                );
                // Make div next to h3 open and add class
                $(this).next().addClass('open').animate(
                    {'height':'toggle'}, 'slow', 'linear'
                );
            }
        });
```

Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've probably not understood what you're trying to do, but changing the line:

```
if ($('h3.sectionHeading').next().is('.open')) { // etc
```

To:

```
if ($(this).next().is('.open')) { // etc
```

Will fire the first if statement. As you're using the selector `h3.sectionHeading` the next() object will always be the same. I'm assuming you wanted the next element after the current selection?

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/ocicu4/5/edit).

Comment: Hmm.. yeah, that's exactly it. I'm slightly embarrassed I couldn't figure that out myself. Thanks.